# How can I embed the contents of the "What links here" link in a Mediawiki theme?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to be able to see the list of pages which link to the page I'm currently viewing. Is there an extension or snippet which allows this? Searched but only found old links.

Comment: I found this, which looks promising: https://github.com/automatist/showbacklinks

Comment: "What links here" is an includable special page, you can put `{{Special:WhatLinksHere/{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}` into some text that appears everywhere. This will probably blow up and I am not recommending it as a good solution :) but if you don't find anything else you could try.

Comment: @Tgr, that works, thanks! But, it means I need to include it in every page text. I'm going to try the link above and integrate the same method into the theme.

Comment: You could probably combine it with something like [PageNotice](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageNotice). Again, I am not recommending it :) What showbacklinks.php does is the sane approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension works fine: https://github.com/automatist/showbacklinks, but it doesn't handle redirects, just ignores them. I have made some modifications, here: https://github.com/benparsons/showbacklinks which makes the plugin behave as if you were inserting the contents of Special:WhatLinksHere into the bottom of every article.